# How to work with local html files in CefSharp v57 for Revit 2019

Tags: c#-4.0, cefsharp, revit

I am working on a project where I need to use CefSharp on for Revit plugin. 
I could complete the task with CefSharp v65 and tried the same with v67 with local html, css and js files.

```
public static string rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Replace("testapp.dll\\", "");

public MainView()
{
    this.chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Format(@"{0}\ui\test.html", MainView.rootPath));
        this.Controls.Add(this.chromeBrowser);
    if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache");
        settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(MainView.rootPath, "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
        settings.LocalesDirPath = Path.Combine(MainView.rootPath, "locales");
        settings.ResourcesDirPath = Path.Combine(MainView.rootPath);
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
    }
}
```

Form Load

```
    private void MainView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
        string page = string.Format(@"{0}\ui\test.html", MainView.rootPath);
        string downloadpg = System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(string.Format(page, MainView.rootPath));
        this.chromeBrowser.LoadHtml(string.Format(page, MainView.rootPath), page);
        this.chromeBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;
    }

    public void OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        string pathJS = string.Format(@"{0}\ui\js\app.js", MainView.rootPath);
        if (File.Exists(pathJS))
        {
            string script = File.ReadAllText(pathJS);
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code works perfectly as expected with versions 65 and 67 but since Revit 2019 uses [CefSharp version 57](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-2019-1-add-in-and-cefsharp-library/td-p/8205740), hence I need to make the same work on version 57, and for some reason this does not work as expected.

**Update**

The following changes were made since there were some compile time errors
 The line

```
CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
```

was removed.
This change was compiled but there was a runtime error at the following location.

```
public void OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        string pathJS = string.Format(@"{0}\ui\js\app.js", Form1.rootPath);
        if (File.Exists(pathJS))
        {
            string script = File.ReadAllText(pathJS);
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);// The error occurred here
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception said
Unable to execute javascript at this time, scripts can only be executed within a V8Context.Use the IWebBrowser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame property to guard against this exception.

The loadHtml method does not display the local Html files on screen
How to make this work in version 57 of CefSharp.

Please help

Thankyou

Comment: What does your code look like that targets version  57? The code above wouldn't even compile with 57 installed.

Comment: Yes you are right, this code does not compile. Here I am showing what I had done to make it work in v65 and v67. The same didn't work in v57. Anyways I have updated the description. Thank You for your reply.

Comment: Does your `html` page have any javascript on it? If not then it won't have a context, it probably works in newer versions as that check was disabled due to chromium changes. You can execute the script directly on the frame to avoid the check.

Comment: I have scripts tags for js and link tags for css, do I have to remove the css and js references from the html? Could you please guide me with this

Comment: Strange, anyway you can still avoid the check by using the method on the `IFrame` method directly, cannot remember if the name matches exactly, you should have no problem finding it.

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/ for the api doc links